# How to define Dictionary of array values in swift?

Tags: swift

I Want to store something like this in swift 3/4.

```
{
"theme_rgb":[ 12, 44],
"theme_cyan" : [33, 44, 44]
}
```

For above I am trying to define a dictionary with the key as string type and value as the array type. When I tried to initialize it as empty one like below it says ambiguous expression. Can you please help me to correct the syntax in swift 3/4. I am curious to know both shorthand syntax and any other syntax.

```
var emojiesDict =  [String: [Int]()]()
```

Comment: You don't need the brackets behind the array. Just do `var emojiesDict =  [String: [Int]]() `

Comment: "Dictionary of array values" would be more appropriate in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var emojiesDict: [String:[Int]] = [:]

emojiesDict["theme_rgb"] = [12, 44]
emojiesDict["theme_cyan"] = [33, 44, 44]
```